# Does sign language count as a Hefsek between Netilas Yadayim and Hamotzei?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, speech-talking, hefsek-interruption, hamotzi-beracha

May one communicate via sign language (like [ASL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language)) with others (whether or not one is deaf-mute) after washing one's hands before Hamotzei, or would this constitute a Hefsek?

Answer (score 1):

There is a popular misconception that the problem with speaking between Netilas Yadayim and Hamotzi is a hefsek. That is not actually true. The problem is *hesech hada'as*, or being distracted from guarding your hands. [See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 166 and Mishna Berurah there.] So talking with sign language should be the same problem. (Although maybe you could argue you are using your hands so your mind isn't distracted from them.)

Comment: What about where there is an issue of hefsek, like between brachos etc.?

Comment: @shmosel I don't know. Interesting question.